# in case I have two versions of show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say, I will have two versions of `show.html.erb` for the same model.

The first one, which is default, I will call as `show.html.erb`.

The second one, for example - `show1.html.erb`.

So, I want to use the 1st one to show on the browser, and 2nd one for print.

Do I have to create a method for this in the controller?

In general is it possible to create other views besides those that are created by scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use this `wicked_pdf` gem: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf to generate pdf for print:

Add `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf`

to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`

in show method:

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name"
      end
    end
  end
```

now you'll just need to create a `show.pdf.erb` file and use it for your printing.

Comment: Thanks, I found also some railscasts regarding PDF.

Comment: I knew there was one, I used it a year ago and I just couldn't find the link to put it here.

Comment: Here's the link http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=pdf. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Yea, I've seen this, looks like I used a tutorial that's not railscasts, anyway, this is easy to add to your app based on documentations they have.

Comment: Thanks! If it happens you recall, please let me know. :)

Comment: well, it was this one http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit?view=asciicast, I just got the bottom of the page and there he says about wickedpdf and decided to use that one. So I added without tutorial. I even hava a question on SO about image render in pdf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777924/wicked-pdf-image-rendering take a look, you might need it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use different formats of output using respond_to method

Let's say you will need html and text versions

```
def action
  # do some logic
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.text
  end
end
```

In this case for route ".../action" show.html.erb will be rendered. And for ".../action.txt" show.text.erb will be rendered. You could customize template name by passing them in block like `format.text { render 'show1' }`

Look more: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to